# Replacing childFragment with another childFragment put view on top

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment inside which there is another fragment which is child fragment and it will be shown only in the bottom half of the screen whereas parent fragment is a full screen view. I want to replace my child fragment with another child fragment. I followed the standard fragment replacement process but it shows me the new fragment on top of old child fragment.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Below is my xml file containing the parent fragment.

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.HomeActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
            android:text="@string/title_mirror"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Below is my parent fragment xml file containing child fragment:

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.smartmirror.emedsim.ui.mirror.DraggingPanel
        android:id="@+id/outer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/queen_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/transparent_black"
                android:weightSum="3">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/up_arrow"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_video"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </FrameLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </com.smartmirror.emedsim.ui.mirror.DraggingPanel>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is my file adding the child fragment from parent fragment:

```
 private void initViews(View view) {
        mDraggingPanel = view.findViewById(R.id.outer_layout);
        mMainLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        Fragment childFragment = new DiscoveryFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_video, childFragment).commit();
    }
```

Above first child fragment added successfully.
Now I am trying to replace the above child fragment with the new child in my adapter class like below:

```
private void proceedFurther(int position, View v) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
       Fragment childFragment = new VideoIntroScreen();
        childFragment.setArguments(args);
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_video, childFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get the solution for my answer. I am answering in case if anyone needs it.

I just added **?android:windowBackground** in my fragment layout files and solved my view overlapping issue.

Add this to your parent and child fragment root layout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you're using the correct `FragmentManager`. In your `initViews()` method, you're using the child `FragmentManager` of the parent `Fragment. In the`proceedFurther()`method, you're using the`ActivityFragmentManager` (which is hosting the parent fragment).

So you have:

```
Activity
  -> Parent Fragment (in Activity FragmentManager)
     -> Child Fragment 1 (in Parent Fragment Child FragmentManager)
```

In order to replace "Child Fragment 1" properly, you'll need to use the child `FragmentManager` from "Parent Fragment".